# How to set up dial-up connection using xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu

I installed xubuntu on an older machine and can't find the modem or where you set up the internet connection. Where can I find the options or wizard to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the hardware setting up dial-up can be little troublesome, the following link has helped me in setting up my dial-up connection ->
[dialupWIKI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto)

I can't be more specific unless you could tell me model of your modem.

Comment: Link-only answers aren't very useful.  Can you give more details?  Otherwise, your answer will likely be deleted.

Comment: Please expand your answer as suggested by DragonLord.